# Understanding Scroll Depth report

Tags: scroll, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have set up a scroll depth tracker in GTM to track how much visitors scroll down a webpage.

The code seems to work fine, but I don't understand the results.

For example, it shows:

```
10% scroll depth = 949 (14,34%)
20% scroll depth = 901 (13,61%)
30% scroll depth = 861 (13,01%)
40% scroll depth = 813 (12,28%)
```

A screenshot is attached below.

How should these lines be interpreted? First I imagined that only 14,3% of all visitors would scroll down 10%, but that would be literally only the header (which consists of a picture), so it's rather unlikely that people would leave that early.

How should these lines be interpreted?

Thank you!

[image]

Edit: Here is what the GA event looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to consider. First, the behavior of the scroll tracking trigger in Google Tag Manager. Based on the [support article](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679218?hl=en):

> The trigger will only fire once per threshold per page.

So the event will be generated for all thresholds reached, not just the lowest one. You should also be aware of this behavior:

> If a specified scroll depth is visible in the viewport when the page
>   loads, the trigger will fire even though the user has not physically
>   scrolled the page.

Second, the behavior of the Google Analytics reports. The percentage you see, is the share of the current row's quantity compared to the total quantity, for a given column. So on your first image, 949 (number of events for 10 percent threshold) is 14,34% of all tracked scroll events, which is 6620.

Therefore, 100 percent threshold was reached 145 times, which is ~15,3% of 10% events. (It's not clear, if these are global figures for your site, or only a specific page was included, but you can filter your data accordingly.)

Comment: Thank you. The trigger works on a domain base, not on a single page only. Can you please explain what the "6,620" mean? I'm asking because I would assume that only 949 of 6620 visitors saw / scrolled to 10% of my page. Can you shed some light on that?

Comment: From the Analytics UI help: Total Events is the number of times events occurred. So it is not the number of users, but the number of all collected events (hits). If you add up the number of events by percentage (949+901+...+145), it's exactly 6620. Analytics is not aware of the fact, that higher scroll percentage should be subset of events of lower scroll percentages.